# Bright and Dark Fringes In Youngs Double Slit Experiment

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment, interference

In Youngs Double Slit Experiment why do we observe separate bright and dark bands? 
Shouldn't there be a continuous change from a maximum intensity to a minimum intensity (that is 0) and so on, so that we don't observe separate bright and dark bands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful, if you provided a reference or an image.

Yes, in principle we should observe a continuous change in the intensity. However, each sensor has a certain *dynamical range*: It can't resolve the continuous intensity. Therefore, the image will tend to become discretized.  Just take a look at photographs, which are taken towards the sun.

Comment: It is very easy to see a continuous intensity with a proper film and enough exposure time.

Answer (score 0):

In textbooks or on the Internet you see two types of images of the fringes.

Ones which have been produced in a painting application and they look too good to be true

[image]

[image]

others which are a genuine photographs (I think)

[image]

which are often characterised by over exposure in the centre (almost white blobs) to get a reasonable exposure for the higher order fringes.

Theoretically the intensity profile of double slit fringe pattern should look like this

[image]

where the intensity of the $\cos^2$ "interference" fringes is modulated by the single slit diffraction pattern produced by each of the slits.

The eye is much better than any camera at being able to processes a large range of intensities and so by looking at the fringes set up for real you will see that there is a gradation in intensity from one fringe to the next.